# Relational Table Normalization

Tags: relational-database, database-normalization

I would like to know if the relational table in BCNF

Student(StudentNum, NRIC, DateOfBirth, BookTitle)

• Student’s number (StudentNum) uniquely identifies the National Registration Identity Card (NRIC) and the date of birth of the student (DateOfBirth).
• The NRIC determines the student’s date of birth (DateOfBirth).

According to my analysis, the relation is in 2NF. And after changing to BCNF it looks like this

```
Student(StudentNum, NRIC, BookTitle)
StudentDetails(NRIC, DateOfBirth)
```

My query;

1. Before the change 2NF
2. After the change BCNF

Am i correct.

Comment: How does BookTitle relate to all of this? Are you maintaining a list of books owned by a student (for example)?

Comment: @parker.sikand Yes thats right

Answer (score 0):

The idea behind normalization is to eliminate redundancy of rows as much as possible by putting creating additional tables for those columns that may seem to inflict any redundancy on the table.

For example if we start with the following table: Student(StudentNum, NRIC, DateOfBirth, BookTitle) The unique columns in this case are the StudentNum and NRIC, the other 2 fields are not because other students may have the same date of birth and others may have borrowed the book of the same title. From there we see the need to normalize in order for us not to fall into the redundancy of data, for example what if the same student borrowed 100 different books?

If everything is in a single table, we may end up with lots of redundant(repetitive) data.

I suggest you check out this guide to the 5 normal forms http://www.bkent.net/Doc/simple5.htm

Update:

I think the beginning relation better to be considered 1st normal form given that everything is within a single table. Your resulting relation is 2NF I guess because what if different students have borrowed the same book? That may lead to repetition in the Student table.

I think you have to give more info regarding the scenario constituting your relations so we can analyze this better. It highly depends on the business rules.

Comment: other than the 2 points i dont have any other information. Using this information i need to change the relation into a BCNF formed relations/s

Answer (score 0):

No. Student is in 1NF, not 2NF.

You're starting with

```
Student(StudentNum, NRIC, DateOfBirth, BookTitle)
```

and these dependencies.

```
StudentNum->NRIC
StudentNum->DateOfBirth
NRIC->DateOfBirth
```

A relation is in 2NF if and only if

- it's in 1NF, and
- every non-prime attribute is dependent on the *whole* of *every* candidate key, not just on part of *any* candidate key.

So your first job is to determine the candidate keys of the Student relation. The Student relation has only one candidate key, and that's {StudentNum, BookTitle}.

Your textbook should have at least one algorithm for determining all the candidate keys of a relation.

Since NRIC is dependent on StudentNum, and StudentNum isn't a candidate key (it's just *part* of a candidate key), the relation Student is not in 2NF. Fix that by changing

```
Student(StudentNum, NRIC, DateOfBirth, BookTitle)
```

to this, by eliminating the partial key dependency on StudentNum.<sup>1</sup>

- Student (**StudentNum**, NRIC, DateOfBirth)
- StudentBooks (**StudentNum, BookTitle**)

StudentBooks has no non-prime attributes at all; it's now in 6NF. Student is in 2NF, but not yet in 3NF or BCNF. Do you know why?

It seems you *did* know why. There is indeed a transitive dependency: StudentNum->NRIC, and 
NRIC->DateOfBirth. Fix the transitive dependency like this.

- Student (**StudentNum**, NRIC)
- NRIC (**NRIC**, DateOfBirth)
- StudentBooks (**StudentNum, BookTitle**)

All three of those relations are in 6NF.

---

1. This decomposition might *look* a little odd. That's because textbook examples usually don't use meaningful names for either relations or attributes. Relations are usually named R{ABCD}, R<sub>1</sub>{ABC}, R<sub>2</sub>{AD}, etc. The decomposition above involved

   - projecting a new relation {**StudentNum**, NRIC, DateOfBirth} to eliminate the partial key dependency,
   - observing that the name "Student" no longer identified the relation consisting of {**StudentNum, BookTitle**},
   - moving the name "Student" from the original relation to the new, projected relation, and
   - coming up with a new name, StudentBooks, for the original relation.

Comment: but the main relation Student has transitive dependency. Which means it is in 2NF. Only if a relation has partial dependency than it is in 1NF. Am i right ?

Comment: I think English is not your first language, although your English is very good. You're *basically* right, but I'd say it differently. "Student" has a transitive dependency, so it's not in 3NF. (Strictly speaking, it *could* be in either 1NF or 2NF.) If a relation has a partial key dependency, it's *not* in 2NF. (It's either in 1NF, or it's not really a relation at all. "Not really a relation at all" actually happens in the real world.)